# What is best deployment practice for block-chain nodes?

Tags: nodes, decentralization

What is the best practice for the deployment of block-chain/peers node? Is it best to have all the node in single cloud server or it should be decentralized and co-located on different server at different locations ?

Comment: This will really just depend on your use case and what the goal is.